# How can I create another column counting the instances of value in a specific criterion?

Tags: sql

I have this table

| Subject | Student |
| --- | --- |
| Math | Jake |
| Math | Cris |
| Math | Jane |
| Science | Elaine |
| Science | Dolly |
| Arts | Evan |
| PE | Margo |
| PE | Ben |
| PE | Ross |
| PE | Jill |
| History | Ace |

I want to create a table like this

| Subject | Student | Student Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Math | Jake | 3 |
| Math | Cris | 3 |
| Math | Jane | 3 |
| Science | Elaine | 2 |
| Science | Dolly | 2 |
| Arts | Evan | 1 |
| PE | Margo | 4 |
| PE | Ben | 4 |
| PE | Ross | 4 |
| PE | Jill | 4 |
| History | Ace | 1 |

I basically want to add a column that counts how many students are there per subject. How can I do this in sql?

I know COUNT is the solution but I need more details.

Comment: If you have to do it as a table (as opposed to a view) you need a trigger to update that column with every change to the table. I'd you are ok to create a view when the view can have SQL with count(*) over (partition by subject) as student count.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS (sql server, mysql ...) you are using

Comment: As already said, create a  view. Or at least use triggers. (Storing such calculated values too often ends up in data inconsistency.)

Comment: `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Subject)`

Answer (score -1):

oops sorry, this is wrong ...

```
SELECT c_subject, MAX(student) Student, COUNT(*) Student_Count 
FROM #classes 
GROUP BY c_subject;
```

Charlie was right ...

```
SELECT c_subject, student, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c_subject)
FROM #classes student_count;
```

Comment: OP wants to keep all rows, just add a count column. This GROUP BY will reduce the number of rows.